# Can I rewrite this Cypher query to be compatible with Redis Graph?

Tags: cypher, redisgraph

My use-case is that I have some agents in organisation structure. I want select for *some agent* (*can by me*) to see sum (*amount of money*) of all contracts that that agents subordinates (*and subordinates of their subordinates and so on...*) created with clients grouped by contract category.

Problem is that Redis Graph [do not currently support](https://github.com/RedisGraph/RedisGraph/issues/1059) `all` predicate. But I need to filter relations between agents because we have multiple "modules" with different organisation structures and I need report just from one module at the time.

My current Cypher query is:

```
MATCH path = (:agent {id: 482})<-[:supervised *]-(b:agent)
    WHERE all(rel IN relationships(path) WHERE
        rel.module_id = 1
        AND rel.valid_from < '2020-05-29'
        AND '2020-05-29' < rel.valid_to)
WITH b as mediators
MATCH (mediators)-[:mediated]->(c:contract)
    RETURN
        c.category as category,
        count(c) as contract_count,
        sum(c.sum) as sum
    ORDER BY sum DESC, category
```

This query works in Neo4j.

I don't event know if this query is correctly written for the type of result that I want.

My boss would really like to use Redis Graph instead Neo4j because of performance reasons but I can't find any way to rewrite this query to be functional in the Redis graph. Is it even possible?

**Edit 1:** I was told that we will be using graph just for currently valid data and just for one module so I no longer need functional `all` predicate but I am still interested in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ALL` function isn't supported at the moment, we do intend to add it in the near future, an awkward way of achieving the same effect as the `ALL` function would be a combination of `UNWIND` and `count`

```
MATCH path = (:agent {id: 482})<-[:supervised *]-(b:agent)
WITH b AS b, relationships(path) AS edges, size(relationships(path)) AS edge_count
UNWIND edges AS r
WITH b AS b, edge_count AS edge_count, r AS r
WHERE r.module_id = 1 AND r.valid_from < '2020-05-29' AND '2020-05-29' < r.valid_to
WITH b AS b, edge_count AS edge_count, count(r) AS filter_edge_count
WHERE edge_count = filter_edge_count
....
```